# Dynamically update attribute "Title" for an input tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

```js
let addMoreInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.addMoreInputs')
let addSections = document.querySelectorAll('.addSections')
let fieldTags = ['Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth']

for (let addMore of addMoreInputs) {
  let counter = -1

  addMore.onclick = () => {
    counter = counter + 1
    let inputType = addMore.parentElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1]
    let moreDetails = inputType.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[3];


    let moreStartDate = `
         <input type="date" placeholder="Start Date" name="dates" aria-autocomplete="none" autocomplete="off" id="startDate" title=" ${ fieldTags[ counter ] } Start Date" class="startDate placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest"
      />
          `

    let moreDayInput = `
      <select name="aptDay" id="aptDay" title="${ fieldTags[ counter ] } Appointment Start Day"
                            class="aptDay placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest">
                      <option value="" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Pick a day
                      </option>
                      <option value="Monday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Monday
                      </option>
                      <option value="Tuesday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Tuesday
                      </option>
                      <option value="Wednesday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Wednesday
                      </option>
                      <option value="Thursday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Thursday
                      </option>
                      <option value="Friday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Friday
                      </option>
                      <option value="Saturday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Saturday
                      </option>
                      <option value="Sunday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
                        Sunday
                      </option>
                    </select>
    `

    let inputWrapper = document.createElement('div')
    inputWrapper.classList.add('relative', 'flex', 'items-center', 'w-full')

    let inputHolder = document.createElement('div')
    inputHolder.classList.add('w-full')

    let deleteDateInput = document.createElement('span')
    deleteDateInput.innerHTML = `
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 p-1 rounded-full text-rose-600 ml-2 deleteExtraDateInput cursor-pointer ease-in-out duration-300">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.5 4.478v.227a48.816 48.816 0 013.878.512.75.75 0 11-.256 1.478l-.209-.035-1.005 13.07a3 3 0 01-2.991 2.77H8.084a3 3 0 01-2.991-2.77L4.087 6.66l-.209.035a.75.75 0 01-.256-1.478A48.567 48.567 0 017.5 4.705v-.227c0-1.564 1.213-2.9 2.816-2.951a52.662 52.662 0 013.369 0c1.603.051 2.815 1.387 2.815 2.951zm-6.136-1.452a51.196 51.196 0 013.273 0C14.39 3.05 15 3.684 15 4.478v.113a49.488 49.488 0 00-6 0v-.113c0-.794.609-1.428 1.364-1.452zm-.355 5.945a.75.75 0 10-1.5.058l.347 9a.75.75 0 101.499-.058l-.346-9zm5.48.058a.75.75 0 10-1.498-.058l-.347 9a.75.75 0 001.5.058l.345-9z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>

          `

    if (inputType.getAttribute('id') === 'startDate') {
      inputHolder.innerHTML = moreStartDate
    }

    if (inputType.getAttribute('id') === 'aptDay') {
      inputHolder.innerHTML = moreDayInput
    }

    if (inputType.getAttribute('id') === 'aptTimeSlot') {
      inputHolder.innerHTML = moreTimeSlotInput
    }

    inputWrapper.appendChild(inputHolder)
    inputWrapper.appendChild(deleteDateInput)
    moreDetails.appendChild(inputWrapper)

    let deleteExtraDateInput = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteExtraDateInput')

    for (let delDateTag of deleteExtraDateInput) {
      delDateTag.onclick = () => {
        counter = -1

        let parentElement = delDateTag.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        parentElement.lastElementChild.remove();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="categoryFields md:grid md:grid-cols-1 md:gap-x-10">

  <!-- Start Date  -->
  <div class="relative h-fit flex flex-col startDateWrapper">

    <div class="default w-full flex items-center">
      <div class="grow relative">
        <input type="date" placeholder="Start Date" name="dates" aria-autocomplete="none" autocomplete="off" id="startDate" title="Appointment Start Date"  class="aptStartDate placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest"
        />

      </div>

      <div class="addMoreInputs ml-5 cursor-pointer">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-indigo-600">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                      d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zM12.75 9a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0v2.25H9a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.25V15a.75.75 0 001.5 0v-2.25H15a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.25V9z"
                      clip-rule="evenodd" />
                  </svg>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="additionalDates addSections grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-10" name="Appointment Start Date">
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Start Day  -->
  <div class="relative h-fit flex flex-col">

    <div class="default w-full flex items-center">

      <div class="grow relative">

        <select name="days" id="aptDay" title="Appointment Start Day" class="aptDay placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest">
          <option value="" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Pick a day
          </option>
          <option value="Monday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Monday
          </option>
          <option value="Tuesday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Tuesday
          </option>
          <option value="Wednesday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Wednesday
          </option>
          <option value="Thursday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Thursday
          </option>
          <option value="Friday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Friday
          </option>
          <option value="Saturday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Saturday
          </option>
          <option value="Sunday" class="text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs">
            Sunday
          </option>
        </select>

      </div>

      <div class="addMoreInputs ml-5 cursor-pointer">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 text-indigo-600">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                      d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zM12.75 9a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0v2.25H9a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.25V15a.75.75 0 001.5 0v-2.25H15a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.25V9z"
                      clip-rule="evenodd" />
                  </svg>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="additionalDay addSections grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-10" name="Appointment Start Day">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

I have a form where there is a date input tag with the option to add multiple dates by appending date input tags in the form. All the new added date tags have dynamic classes and titles.

Adding the dynamic classes and title is working correctly.

However, say I append 3 more date tags in the form having their own class and title like secondDate, thirdDate and fourthDate.

**But when I remove say thirdDate input tag the class and title for remaining date tags should get updated to secondDate and thirdDate (fourthDate tag's class and title should be updated to thirdDate)**

I tried by adding a counter to update the count, but it is not working when I delete a date tag.

How to do I update the class name and title when a particular date tag is deleted and when it is added again so the order is correct?

Edit: Added code snippet.

Comment: The above, when written as a snippet, does not work as described. In the Javascript you reference elements with class  `addMoreDatesBtn` - this does not exist in the HTML. Clicking the SVG icon does nothing. Are the classes assigned dynamically actually named `thirdDate`,`fourthDate` etc or some other? Please clarify and provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius added the code snippet.

Comment: With the above code if one adds more than 5 new elements the title becomes `undefined start day` or `undefined appointment...` etc

Comment: It appears that you will be duplicating ID attributes which will invalidate the HTML and is possibly going to cause unforeseen issues

Comment: There is a check which prevents from adding more than 5 tags. Duplicating ID attributes, how? Title would be unique since they will added dynamically from the array of classes. Eventually I would store all values (default + appended) in an array to further work on them hence one common attribute.

Answer (score 0):

After some minor modifications to the original HTML, such as:-

1. Add `data-type` attribute to both `div.addSections` containers that reflect the type of title to be added.
2. Removed pointless and invalid `name` attribute from these same div elements.
3. Created a new `SVG` with a `defs` section at the bottom of the document so that the `path` elements could be stored there, assign IDs and referenced in the HTML using a `use` element to avoid duplicating SVG content unnecessarily.

With those minor changes in place, a statically rendered example that replicates 3 dynamically added elements within each of the above named DIV elements. The example HTML does not have any `title` attributes written - these `title` attributes are written here dynamically **only** for convenience and to replicate what might happen when the user adds new content.

The `delete` and `re-sequence` of these title attributes is the focus of this answer so none of the original code to `add` elements nor the icons or original form elements are depicted below.

To observe effects, HOVER over elements before & after deleting from the DOM. The sequence is modified each time an element & it's children are removed thus reflecting the ordinal position correctly.

```js
const fieldTags = ['Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth'];
const suffix=' Appointment Start ';

/**************************************************
  This ONLY adds the title to the input or select
  to replicate(!) what would happend when a user
  clicks on the "Add" button/icon.
  
  This is for setup here only!!!
  
  Mouseover each of the 3 items in each `addSections`
  div to view the title assigned. Note they are named
  as per the fieldTags variable for that item's DOM
  position index & array position.
*/
document.querySelectorAll('.addSections').forEach(div=>{
  div.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"],select').forEach( (n,index)=>{
    let type=div.dataset.type;
    let title=fieldTags[ index ] + suffix + type;
    n.title=title;
  })
});


/*************************************************
  To re-sequence the names of dynamically added
  content when the `delete` svg icon is clicked
  this queries the DOM after the input element
  & it's parent have been removed from the DOM
  using `querySelectorAll`
  
  The nodelist is iterated through using `forEach`
  which can take 3 arguments, the second of which
  is the elements index within the nodelist.
  
  This index is used to build the new title based
  upon the fieldTags array.
  
  The event listener is a delegated listener bound
  to the document ( or suitable parent container )
  and responds ONLY to clicks on the delete SVG.
*/
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target.hasAttribute('href') || e.target.querySelector('use').hasAttribute('href') ){
    let parent=e.target.closest('div.relative');
    let section=parent.closest('.addSections');
    
    parent.parentNode.removeChild( parent );
    
    
    section.querySelectorAll('div.relative').forEach( ( div, index )=>{
      div.querySelector('input,select').title=fieldTags[ index ] + suffix + section.dataset.type;
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.addSections{
  margin:3rem 0;
  border:1px dotted grey;
  padding:1rem
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- example rendered HTML -->
<!-- additional start dates -->
<div class='addSections' data-type='Date'>
  <div class='relative flex items-center w-full'>
    <div class='w-full'>
      <input type='date' placeholder='Start Date' name='dates' aria-autocomplete='none' autocomplete='off' class='startDate placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest'>
    </div>
    <span>
      <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='currentColor' class='w-6 h-6 p-1 rounded-full text-rose-600 ml-2 deleteExtraDateInput cursor-pointer ease-in-out duration-300'>
        <use href="#trash" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class='relative flex items-center w-full'>
    <div class='w-full'>
      <input type='date' placeholder='Start Date' name='dates' aria-autocomplete='none' autocomplete='off' class='startDate placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest'>
    </div>
    <span>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 p-1 rounded-full text-rose-600 ml-2 deleteExtraDateInput cursor-pointer ease-in-out duration-300">
        <use href="#trash" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class='relative flex items-center w-full'>
    <div class='w-full'>
      <input type='date' placeholder='Start Date' name='dates' aria-autocomplete='none' autocomplete='off' class='startDate placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest'>
    </div>
    <span>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 p-1 rounded-full text-rose-600 ml-2 deleteExtraDateInput cursor-pointer ease-in-out duration-300">
        <use href="#trash" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>





<!-- additional start days -->
<div class='addSections' data-type='Day'>
  <div class='relative flex items-center w-full'>
    <div class='w-full'>
      <select name='aptDay' class='aptDay placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest'>
        <option selected hidden disabled class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Pick a day
        <option value='Monday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Monday</option>
        <option value='Tuesday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Tuesday
        <option value='Wednesday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Wednesday
        <option value='Thursday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Thursday
        <option value='Friday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Friday
        <option value='Saturday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Saturday
        <option value='Sunday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Sunday
      </select>
    </div>
    <span>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 p-1 rounded-full text-rose-600 ml-2 deleteExtraDateInput cursor-pointer ease-in-out duration-300">
        <use href="#trash" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class='relative flex items-center w-full'>
    <div class='w-full'>
      <select name='aptDay' class='aptDay placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest'>
        <option selected hidden disabled class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Pick a day
        <option value='Monday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Monday</option>
        <option value='Tuesday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Tuesday
        <option value='Wednesday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Wednesday
        <option value='Thursday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Thursday
        <option value='Friday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Friday
        <option value='Saturday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Saturday
        <option value='Sunday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Sunday
      </select>
    </div>
    <span>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 p-1 rounded-full text-rose-600 ml-2 deleteExtraDateInput cursor-pointer ease-in-out duration-300">
        <use href="#trash" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class='relative flex items-center w-full'>
    <div class='w-full'>
      <select name='aptDay' class='aptDay placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 rounded-md tracking-widest'>
        <option selected hidden disabled class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Pick a day
        <option value='Monday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Monday</option>
        <option value='Tuesday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Tuesday
        <option value='Wednesday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Wednesday
        <option value='Thursday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Thursday
        <option value='Friday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Friday
        <option value='Saturday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Saturday
        <option value='Sunday' class='text-xs md:font-semibold md:text-xs'>Sunday
      </select>
    </div>
    <span>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 p-1 rounded-full text-rose-600 ml-2 deleteExtraDateInput cursor-pointer ease-in-out duration-300">
        <use href="#trash" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>



























<svg>
  <defs>
    <path id="plus" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 
      9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zM12.75 
      9a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0v2.25H9a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.25V15a.75.75 0 001.5 
      0v-2.25H15a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.25V9z" 
      clip-rule="evenodd" />
    <path id="trash" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.5 4.478v.227a48.816 48.816 0 
      013.878.512.75.75 0 11-.256 1.478l-.209-.035-1.005 13.07a3 3 0 01-2.991 
      2.77H8.084a3 3 0 01-2.991-2.77L4.087 6.66l-.209.035a.75.75 0 01-.256-1.478A48.567 
      48.567 0 017.5 4.705v-.227c0-1.564 1.213-2.9 2.816-2.951a52.662 52.662 0 013.369 
      0c1.603.051 2.815 1.387 2.815 2.951zm-6.136-1.452a51.196 51.196 0 013.273 0C14.39 
      3.05 15 3.684 15 4.478v.113a49.488 49.488 0 00-6 0v-.113c0-.794.609-1.428 
      1.364-1.452zm-.355 5.945a.75.75 0 10-1.5.058l.347 9a.75.75 0 
      101.499-.058l-.346-9zm5.48.058a.75.75 0 10-1.498-.058l-.347 9a.75.75 
      0 001.5.058l.345-9z" 
      clip-rule="evenodd" />
  </defs>
</svg>
```

An observation after looking at the above Javascript, where you have:

```
delDateTag.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement; 
parentElement.lastElementChild.remove();
```

You would likely find it easier to:

1. use a delegated event listener rather than add an `onclick` to each icon individually.
2. use `node.closest(expr)` to identify suitable parent element!